# Use Pandas to convert column of non continuous dates to hourly values of those dates

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a list of non-continuous dates. I'm reading these into a dataframe and would like convert to those dates to an hourly level.

All of my searching led to resampling. I managed to convert the date column to a DateTimeIndex and resample, however that filled in every single hour from the first date to the last, and I'm looking for just 24 hours at a time.

```
d = {'date': ["1/1/2014", "5/26/2014", "7/4/2014"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.tz_localize('US/Eastern')
df = df.set_index('date')
df = df.resample('H').ffill()
```

This creates a dataframe with an index that contains every (4416 total) hour from 1/1/2014 - 7/4/2014

What I actually want is to have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
date
2014-01-01 00:00:00-05:00
2014-01-01 01:00:00-05:00
2014-01-01 02:00:00-05:00
2014-01-01 03:00:00-05:00
2014-01-01 04:00:00-05:00
2014-01-01 05:00:00-05:00
2014-01-01 06:00:00-05:00
2014-01-01 07:00:00-05:00
2014-01-01 08:00:00-05:00
2014-01-01 09:00:00-05:00
2014-01-01 10:00:00-05:00
2014-01-01 11:00:00-05:00
2014-01-01 12:00:00-05:00
2014-01-01 13:00:00-05:00
2014-01-01 14:00:00-05:00
2014-01-01 15:00:00-05:00
2014-01-01 16:00:00-05:00
2014-01-01 17:00:00-05:00
2014-01-01 18:00:00-05:00
2014-01-01 19:00:00-05:00
2014-01-01 20:00:00-05:00
2014-01-01 21:00:00-05:00
2014-01-01 22:00:00-05:00
2014-01-01 23:00:00-05:00
2014-05-26 00:00:00-04:00
2014-05-26 01:00:00-04:00
2014-05-26 02:00:00-04:00
2014-05-26 03:00:00-04:00
2014-05-26 04:00:00-04:00
2014-05-26 05:00:00-04:00
2014-05-26 06:00:00-04:00
2014-05-26 07:00:00-04:00
2014-05-26 08:00:00-04:00
2014-05-26 09:00:00-04:00
2014-05-26 10:00:00-04:00
2014-05-26 11:00:00-04:00
2014-05-26 12:00:00-04:00
2014-05-26 13:00:00-04:00
2014-05-26 14:00:00-04:00
2014-05-26 15:00:00-04:00
2014-05-26 16:00:00-04:00
2014-05-26 17:00:00-04:00
2014-05-26 18:00:00-04:00
2014-05-26 19:00:00-04:00
2014-05-26 20:00:00-04:00
2014-05-26 21:00:00-04:00
2014-05-26 22:00:00-04:00
2014-05-26 23:00:00-04:00
```

And then again skipping to 7/4 and just including the 24 hours of that date.

Comment: Are there any columns in your frame of just the date as an index?

Comment: @It_is_Chris Initially it's just the column of dates. I'm actually reading it in from a CSV. I converted that column to the index so I could use resample, but I'm not opposed to doing something different to get the result I want. The end goal is to use the column of each date and all 24 hours of it as a condition to change another column in another data frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of resampling, create a date range of `date` to `date + 24h` with a frequency of `1H` for each date, and then explode them all together:

```
hours = df['date'].apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x, x + pd.tseries.offsets.Hour(23), freq='1H')).explode()
```

Output:

```
>>> hours
0   2014-01-01 00:00:00-05:00
0   2014-01-01 01:00:00-05:00
0   2014-01-01 02:00:00-05:00
0   2014-01-01 03:00:00-05:00
0   2014-01-01 04:00:00-05:00
               ...           
2   2014-07-04 19:00:00-04:00
2   2014-07-04 20:00:00-04:00
2   2014-07-04 21:00:00-04:00
2   2014-07-04 22:00:00-04:00
2   2014-07-04 23:00:00-04:00
Name: date, Length: 72, dtype: datetime64[ns, US/Eastern]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, I think the good thing to use is `pd.date_range` from pandas package.
You can do like this for the first date and concatenate it to implement the others (you can make it with a loop).

```
pd.date_range(start='1/1/2014', end = '2/1/2014', freq='1H')
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
hours = df.apply(lambda df_: df_['date'] + pd.to_timedelta(range(24), unit='H'), axis=1).explode()
```